# Relation between roots and coefficients of an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $p,q,r $ are the roots of the equation $x^3 - 3px^2 + 3q^2x - r^3 = 0$

Hello! I hope everybody is doing well. Can anybody please help me with the above problem?

> My Solution: From Vieta’s $p+q+r = 3p$. Hence $q+ r = 2p$ Which yields $q,p,r $ is an AP. Also, $pqr = r^3 $ which gets $pq=r^2 $ and hence $q,r,p $ is a GP. Since the triplet is an AP and GP at the same time $p=q=r$. Done!

I just want to know if the proof above is right or not. Am I missing something? Or is the proof complete? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have assumed that because $q,p,r$ is an AP and $q,r,p$ is a GP then the variables have to be equal.

However, that is not true. A nice counterexample is found by taking

$$q=\sqrt 2,p=\sqrt 2+1,r=\sqrt 2+2.$$

N.B. To solve your problem you can use $q+r=2p$ and $pq=r^2$ to obtain$$2p^2-2pr-r^2=0$$ and therefore $r=p$ or $r=-2p$ etc.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for answering! So, What is the mistake in this proof: Let the elements be $a-d,a,a+d$. Since they are in GP also, $a^2 - d^2 = a^2 $ and we get $-d^2 = 0$. In other words $d=0$.

Comment: @Vasu090 why don't you plug the sequence of this answer in your argument and see the problem?

Comment: You have just assumed that the order of the series stays the same but in your problem the order changes: q,p,r then q,r,p.

Comment: @gt6989b I am just asking to find the mistake, I agree that the sequence may be an AP and GP at the same time..
BTW What would be a correct proof?

Answer (score 2):

If denote $q=p-a$, then AP will look like 
$$
(q,p,r) = (p-a,\; p,\; p+a),  
$$
the product $pqr$ will look like
$$
pqr=r^3,
$$
$$
(p-a)p(p+a)=(p+a)^3.
$$

Case A: $r=0$: $$p+q=3p, pq=3q^2 \;\;\Rightarrow \;p=q=r=0.$$

Case B: $r\ne 0$:
$$
(p-a)p=(p+a)^2,
$$
$$
3ap+a^2=0.
$$

Case B1: $a=0$ - considered by you.

Case B2 ($a\ne 0, r\ne 0$): 
$a=-3p$, and
$$
(q,p,r)=(4p, p, -2p).
$$

---

**Note** that
$$
(q,p,r) = (4p,p,-2p) \;\; \leftarrow AP
$$
$$
(p,r,q) = (p,-2p,4p) \;\; \leftarrow GP
$$

---

The condition 
$$
pq+qr+pr=3q^2
$$
will clarify the value for $p$ ($p=0$ in this case).

Answer (score 1):

We have:

(1) $p+q+r = 3p$

(2) $pq + qr + pr = 3q^2$

(3) $pqr = r^3$

Case 1: $r=0, q=0\\ \Rightarrow p=3p \\ \Rightarrow p=q=r=0$

Case 2: $r=0, q \ne 0 \\ \Rightarrow q=2p, p=3q$

which is impossible if $q \ne 0$

Case 3: $r \ne0, q \ne 0 \\ \Rightarrow pq=r^2 \\ \Rightarrow r(p+q+r)=3q^2 \\ \Rightarrow pr=q^2 \\ \Rightarrow q^3=r^3 \\\Rightarrow p=q=r$